# asp.net mvc hyperlink a page?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a mvc project and I need to link a page using a hyperlink.I tried like this

```
  <a href="@Url.Action("mylinkpage", "Home")" class="something"><div class="someclass">1</div></a>
```

but its showing page cannot displayed error.What can be the reason?

structure is Views> Home > mylinkpage.cshtml

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Action is a method in a controller.

You should have.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult mylinkpage(string id)
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternate you can try

```
 @Html.ActionLink("1", "mylinkpage","Home", new { }, new { @class = "something" })
```